# How to run su command remotely

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, remote-access, amazon-web-services

I'm a big fan of aliases that save time. Currently I'm supposed to ssh into our remote aws instance by running this command first:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem ubuntu@domain.io
```

then I should run these two commands

```
sudo su - userName
source ~/set_env_vars.env
```

I would like to put them all in a single alias line like so:

```
alias logbnp='ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem ubuntu@beneple.gtl.io -t "sudo su - userName; source ~/set_env_vars.env"'
```

but then I get this error

```
$ logbnp
No passwd entry for user 'userName'
Connection to domain.io closed.
```

any ideas?

Comment: There is no way you can combine `su` with `source` this way because they are normally interpreted by different processes. `No passwd entry for user` message however indicates the problem with `su` command itself. You don't get it when you run `sudo su - userName`?

Comment: no i don't.. and based on some brief research i found that you can change some settings (on the same machine obviously) that creates a white list of users that don't need to set a password apparently

Comment: What is the result of `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem ubuntu@beneple.gtl.io -t "sudo su - userName"`?

Comment: same result as in my question

Comment: why `sudo su - userName`?  Isn't easier to run `sudo -iu userName`? Does that result in something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

to

```
/etc/sudoers
```

on the remote server

Comment: I've edited your answer into something more of that form. That said, without actually saying what this does or why it works, the answer feels incomplete

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: IMHO, this answer does not meet the minimum quality requirements for a SE forum. I vote to delete it.